# Orbit slider works but how to add bullet navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, orbit

I've searched for this but haven't been able to find the one thing i need.
I would like to use my own bullets in orbit slider.

Now my questions: - How can i add my bullets (slider is working but i don't know how to add the bullets)
- And how can i let the bullets change? because i made an image for when it's selected and one for when it isn't selected.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the link of the plugin?

Comment: http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider

There you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see these code in orbit.css file

```
.orbit-bullets li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #999;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url(/playground/playground/jquery-image-slider-plugin/orbit/bullets.jpg) no-repeat 4px 0;
    width: 13px;
    height: 12px;
    overflow: hidden; }

.orbit-bullets li.active {
    color: #222;
    background-position: -8px 0; }
```

But it uses the [image sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

If you have separate images for each, use the background property of each to specify the image.

Comment: But do i have to change something in the html too? i suppose i have to create a class orbit-bullets but i'm not sure

Comment: @jochemke no need to create, plugin will automatically add those classes. Only you need to activate the plugin, and follow the same element structure as per the documentation.

Comment: Here's what i have in the script

          

    `$(window).load(function() {
         $('#featured').orbit();
         bullets: true
         });`

Comment: And Css: I have the same as posted above (changed my image to 2 bullets one selected one not, into 1 image instead of separated)

Comment: @jochemke Should be `$(window).load(function() { $('#featured').orbit({bullets: true}); });`

Comment: Thanks I didn't even notice i forgot to add the brackets xo.